# Spring Integration - how to delegate error handling to separate thread

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

My Spring Integration Flow looks like the below,

1. Read file from directory
2. Add a header called errorChannel:'exceptionChannel' to the message
3. Perform business logic
4. Print output to a 'success directory'

If there is an error on step 3, the exception is sent to the exceptionChannel,and is written to a 'failed directory'.
***I want the error flow to be delegated to a separate thread.***

**What I have:** 
If there are 5 files and the third file has an error,

-> 2 files are written to the success directory

-> 1 file is written to the failed directory.

-> The flow stops after the error file.

**What I need:**
If there are 5 files and the third file has an error,

-> First 2 files must be written to success directory

-> 3rd file must be written to failed directory

-> Last 2 files must be written to success directory

**Code for Success flow:**

```
@Bean(name="exceptionChannel")
MessageChannel exceptionChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow migrateInputToOutput() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(INPUT_DIR))),
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("errorChannel", "exceptionChannel", true))
            .handle(someBusinessLogic) // ANY EXCEPTION HERE IS SENT TO exceptionChannel
            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(OUTPUT_SUCCESS_DIR))
            .get();
}
```

**Code for handling error:**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow handleErrorInMigration() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("exceptionChannel"),
            .handle(errorLogicToPrintException)
            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(OUTPUT_ERROR_DIR))
            .get();
}
```

Comment: @ArtemBilan - can you please help?

Comment: @GaryRussell - can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Files.inboundAdapter()` is *pollable source*, so there is somewhere something like `Poller` configured in your code. That one has a `errorChannel()` option. It is really would be better to do that way. If your poller is global one and you don't want to modify it, it is better to have a poller configured exactly for this endpoint:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(INPUT_DIR)), 
        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay().errorChannel(exceptionChannel())))
```

This way you won't effect all other polling endpoints.

To move your error handling to different thread, you need to consider to make that `exceptionChannel` as an `ExecutorChannel`:

```
@Bean(name="exceptionChannel")
MessageChannel exceptionChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor(myExecutor)
            .get();
}
```

Comment: MessageChannels.executor worked for me. Accepting answer.